# How to trigger a method once an option from a drop down list is selected in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So the code for the drop down list is the following, and once the user clicks on one of the options I want to trigger a method in the controller, but not sure how.  And how do I access the value from the controller page?

```
<select>
  <option value="" selected="selected">Please select</option>
  <option value="1">Administrator</option>
  <option value="2">User</option>
  <option value="3">Editor</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onChange` feature in jQuery in combination with Ajax.

```
$('select').on('change', function() {
  $.ajax({
    url : '/users',
    type : 'GET',
    data : { user_id: this.value },
    dataType:'script'
  });
})
```

You will also need to add your method in your `routes.rb`

Comment: What should the method in the routes.rb look like?  I added the code to my application.js and added "<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>" to my view, but it's not triggering any action.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it figured out for the most part.  Thank you.

Comment: One last question, how do I access data : { user_id: this.value } from the controller?  I've been able to trigger a method, but am struggling to get the value from the form selected.

Comment: I think you want to use params[:user_id] to get the value from the request. You can also do a debug(params) to see the structure of the params request.